# routeboxer(google maps api) php implementation

Tags: php, routes, maps

How to get the same thing but in php. I can't rely on javascript for data input.

Answer (score 1):

For those who looks for it, I've also developped a java port of RouteBoxer, you can find it : [here](http://code.google.com/p/routeboxer-java/)

This allows to do route boxing (like searching points close enough to a given lat lng path), on server side.

Answer (score 0):

sorry if this is digging up a late thread, just thought i'd post this for posterity.

you can find a PHP class that does the same here : http://www.luktek.com/?q=node/4

there is a small change in the class (line 10, i seem to remember). just make sure you correct that and you'll be fine!

hope it helps.